# how to fix error unnpr after minify with gulp-babel-minify

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, gulp-babel

I am doing minify code with gulp-babel-minify and I get some error like this

> ```
> Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: 
> aProvider <- a <- $http <- $templateFactory <- $view <- $state
> ```

**NEW UPDATE**

finally i get the error after i minify
and this is code from app.js :

```
    app.config(['$httpProvider', '$qProvider',function($httpProvider, $qProvider){
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptors');
  $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
    //HANDLE LOST CONN 1 WITH NEW PAGE
     $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
        return {
          responseError: function(rejection) {
                if(rejection.status <= 0) {
                    window.location = "../noresponse.html";
                    return rejection;
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    });

}]);
```

so is there really a wrong part of the code there? 
so how to handle `Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: aProvider <- a <- $http <- $templateFactory <- $view <- $state`??